# How to prevent indent on \listofalgorithms?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, algorithms

How can I prevent the `\listofalgorithms` from being indented? I tried everything I could find on the internet, but the index of my algorithms refused to be aligned along with the title.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\numberwithin{algorithm}{section}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Algorithms}
    \listofalgorithms
    \newpage
    \section{Introduction}\noindent
    Text\\
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{algo:caption}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State hello world
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The indentation is due to how the `\listof` macro works; it's provided by `float` that's loaded by `algorithm`. The easiest way to remove the indent is to patch that command:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\listof}{1.5em}{0pt}{}{}
```

The definition of `\listofalgorithms` is

```
\newcommand{\listofalgorithms}{\listof{algorithm}{\listalgorithmname}}
```

and `\listof` is

```
\newcommand{\listof}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}
    {\float@error{#1}}
    {\@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
     \float@listhead{#2}%
     \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
       \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
     \endgroup}%
}
```

So once we know that `\@dottedtocline` is responsible for the typesetting of the line and `1.5em` is the initial indent, we're done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and accurate response!